# What's the significance of using a generator to prove a cyclic subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, normal-subgroups

I have the main group of a general linear group of order 3, over real numbers. How is it that the below is a cyclic subgroup?

$$H = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & a\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}, a \in integers$$

The point of the question is to understand the importance of generators, but how do I get the generator of a matrix? From there, I'm assuming I can simply use the two-step subgroup test to prove that it is a subgroup. Any idea on why it would be cyclic though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This group is generated by
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&1 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix},$$
which has inverse
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&-1 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
This is the reason it is clearly cyclic --- you can explicitly give the generator.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but can I ask how you got the generator? With the generator we can prove that it is cyclic, just because we have it?

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh I'm sorry to say that I could give this generator because I am very accustomed to matrix multiplication. However, this is very similar to the 2x2 matrix case. Such 2x2 matrices have a natural action on $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by mobius transformations, and this group happens to be the group giving horizontal translations by integer amounts. And this action is clearly generated by horizontal translations by $1$. [I'm sorry that this is a bit further afield than one might expect]

Answer (score 1):

A cyclic subgroup is the subgroup $\{ x^n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ generated by one of its elements $x \in G$, so you would like to find this element.

If you have a matrix $X$ of your form, try calculating its powers $X^n$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. What do you get?